# How to query vacant rooms even it is marked as Dismissed

Tags: mysql

I am having really bad trouble querying my vacant rooms, I have this query

```
select rooms.*
     , ty.* 
  FROM tbl_room rooms 
  JOIN tbl_roomtype ty 
    ON rooms.RoomTypeID = ty.RoomTypeID 
 WHERE rooms.RoomID NOT IN 
          (SELECT t1.RoomID 
             FROM tbl_room t1 
             JOIN tbl_reservationext t2 
               ON t1.RoomID = t2.RoomID 
             JOIN tbl_reservation rr 
               ON t2.ReservationID = rr.ReservationID 
            WHERE NOT('$date_to' < rr.CheckIn_datetime 
                       OR ('$date_from' > rr.CheckOut_datetime)
                      )
          )
```

This query works fine, but it doesn't query those reservations marked as Dismissed.

I tried putting some AND rr.Status != 'Dismissed' but still doesn't work.

Could someone help me.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: thanks a lot i've solved it myself...

Comment: Sharing is caring